# update slim settings from within middleware classe

Tags: php, slim, middleware

I'trying to write a session middleware which checks if a user is logged and have a session. here is the simplified middleware class

Index.php

```
// To help the built-in PHP dev server, check if the request was actually for
// something which should probably be served as a static file
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli-server' && $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] !== __FILE__) {
    return false;
}

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

// Instantiate the app
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../app/settings.php';
$app = new \Slim\App($settings);


// Set up dependencies
require __DIR__ . '/../app/dependencies.php';

// Register middleware
require __DIR__ . '/../app/middleware.php';

// Register routes
require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';

// Run!
$app->run();
```

middleware.php

```
<?php
// Application middleware

$app->add( new App\Middlewares\sessionMiddleWare($container) );
```

And App\Middlewares\sessionMiddleWare

```
<?php
namespace App\Middlewares;

use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use \PDO;

private $database;
private $settings;

class sessionMiddleWare {

    public function __construct($container){
        $this->database = $container['databaselayer'];
        $this->settings = $container['settings'];
    }

    public function __invoke(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $next){
        if(!$_SESSION['util']){
            // Do some stuff (create session variable and set idPageWeb he wants into $this->settings['idPageWeb']
        }
        //then
        if( $_SESSION["idUtil"] ){
            $response = $next($request->withAttribute("idPageWeb",$this->settings["idPageWeb"]), $response);
        }else{
            //forbiden
        }

    }
}
```

My problem is on the first load, this->setting['idPageWeb'] is set correctly, but if I reload, I already have session so pass through next but $this->setting['idPageWeb'] is empty. So my question is how set this var globally? Or saving var into app settings?

thx for help.

Comment: why is the constructor outside of the class (sessionMiddleware)?

Comment: Just use the file `settings.php` for the application settings. Then pass the settings to the middleware contructor.

Comment: @jmattheis just error while copying my code into stackoverflow sorry

Comment: @DanielO. Is it not the case? I get back settings through `$this->settings = $container['settings'];` into my middleware constructor

Comment: Did you call `session_start();` somewhere? If not: Add this line to your session middleware __invoke method (first line).

Comment: yes I did in my index.php file